# Issue with replacing fragment in view pager from another fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I need to replace fragment in view pager in an activity on a nework call success in another fragment. View pager is inside my dashboard activity. Here is get item method

```
 @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (pos) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new SponsorshipOffersFragment();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (mPreferenceManager.getConnectProfileStatus()) {
                        fragment = new CollaborationFragment();
                    } else {
                        fragment = new ConnectSettingFragment();
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new ProtfolioFragment();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fragment = new SocialSummaryFragment();
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }
```

For case 2, first time getConnectProfileStatus will return false and ConnectSettingFragment will get call. After submitting profile from ConnectSettingFragment, on success I need to call CollaborationFragment.

Can someone help me to do ? I am calling below method from fragment

```
public void replaceFrament() {
       mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    }
```

that is inside activity but nothing happening.

Comment: "on a nework call success in another fragment" How ur updating this to your activity ?

Comment: Your `replaceFragment()` method is just setting the current item to `2`. For that value(=2) there is already a fragment attached, so it won't get replaced. For your understanding.. ViewPager is not replacing fragments... You will have to `@override notifyDataSetChanged` I think

Comment: @King of Masses I am calling replace() method from fragment as below  ((DashboardActvitiy)getActivity()).replaceFrament();

Comment: @Ionut J. Bejan DO I need to call notifyDataSetChanged just after  mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2); ??

Comment: Let me explain better : `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);` is simply making the swipe to the specified position. It is not calling `getItem` again.. The `ViewPager` already knows which fragment is on that position...it's not going to re-create the fragments when you change positions

Comment: Okay. Is there a way to call getItem() again or something else to replace fragment?

Comment: For this case you have, I would rather do something else. Use only 1 fragment on `case 2`. And, inside this fragment you could change the layout based on your `submit on success`. To change the layout, take a look at `FragmentManager`